# Drive strength and termination on a 50MHz multi-card backplane bus

Tags: impedance, signal-integrity, bus, termination

I'm helping someone design a spec for a computing ecosystem based on Z80 and Eurocard. One of the challenges is that we want to support modern Z80 chips clocked at up to 50MHz, which means we have to pay much more attention to signal integrity than with older, slower-clocked devices with slower rise/fall times.

Here's a rough outline of the spec as it stands:

- 3.3V logic levels (much older 5V-only Z80 parts can be level shifted)
- All signals are single-ended, 50Ω impedance.
- Impedance controlled PCBs with 4-layer SIG+PWR/GND/GND/SIG+PWR stackup (or similar 6L) mandated for backplane and high-speed cards.
- Backplane connector pinout spec ensures that there's an adjacent GND for every signal.
- Maximum 20pF load capacitance per line (connector parasitics, junction capacitance in TVS clamps, etc.)
- Maximum 50mm distance on each card between the connector edge and driver / termination.
- Backplane slots are undifferentiated; any compliant card can be placed in any slot, and slots may be empty. A system may have just one card installed.
- Backplanes with more than 8 slots must insert suitable buffer ICs every 8 slots.

I hadn't really given much thought to termination until yesterday, but once I did I realised that it's actually non-trivial. I've done a few simulations and think I have a workable solution, but I'd like to check if there are alternative approaches that might work out better.

The rough overall setup looks like this:

[image: Diagram of a backplane with 50 ohm impedance transmission lines between each slot, and 50 ohm transmission lines going from the slots into the cards.]

The bus consists of around 40 signals at a max clock rate of 50MHz. Rather than trying to simulate all 40 signals simultaneously, I'm just looking at one signal. They're all the same physical spec anyway.

The simulations I've done assume a 150mm/ns signal propagation rate, meaning a 135ps delay transmission line between each slot (20mm spacing as per Eurocard spec), roughly a 66ps delay transmission line over the connector (10mm), and a 333ps delay transmission line for the maximum card trace length of 50mm as defined by the spec. I'm also assuming a driver slew rate of *roughly* 1V/ns.

My first thought was a typical parallel resistor termination. However, with eight cards installed, the voltage level of the signal droops significantly due to the 50Ω resistors acting like pulldowns. I solved this by applying a termination voltage of 1.2V at the extents of the backplane:

[image: 8-slot bus driven from slot 1, with VTT attached to slots 1 and 8 via 100 ohm resistors, and 50 ohm parallel termination.]

[(simulate in Falstad)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCBMCmC0YGZwFYB0AWA7JTA2TAnJmGABy5gAMBIC6IyI6SycJAUAErjr1h7gB-XOCgNKEyZXCpcjMLMbTKqZOzKQefAaWnCQemRAWZaqJJXYB3ELHS7BIuw8iVSB9cVv3pr9899sAxkEVnhpZGkETUsAc297KDdvaKT3ZXZ4u0ScTTtU3ODLGwCoINKESnpi7wdK%20gqEERrnR2D9ONrwAjyc5Iz%20CHheNtaOswQENgi9ZszbMBGwHoWRvyLrLvrg7c7W6Ol9po3B1fpt-aqd8ynw8XA5rMXz1zPaY4GvYfpmXvdf66Tab3MBzEqJAHSSGbUroCS1KGpPa8f7w-KaOHKDynRpOHxMeF6cxhKj3JHzbLuSZ41LUjZZFFMXANAHoZknL74tkshzISDpEIkma0GIUxl8-wAiUbcG8-kIhi4DKyxVY5BK7FfZ6qrrqrEIG7AyIPDxPEaM75M6qmroWiHs5UK7lO8myiIrUp6m2tZACH0rDJm%20i%20pza5ABzVDbW4UiS9wxgUGoF3Y2gjwqhPBTMtfFyPEObNixJ5lKaEufIb48N-aTlwVGqKihmJaulhgRnMObCHXOx72JTBXVrd%20lvQcNbUjitvUhp1qz5oTW6k1NgroL4IbzvSTCkHnSLdF9y7lmpE8cytd16lc9E0INkX9gfXgFT9MKvdxg9p5HuUipedEkDGcAO1T8NgAJ2CAgRmkAgI0iTwoxGGCeRAVDAWXYUfxhRIMLg2DcIcAgwBrdDCObdwSN6VJqIvD9ElKOi7yFMkmwSP9GIBcDHSYv18XwsUqI1VoiEXPZtQIETJIEYDLSoPt5Koa1LBxbUqHKRINJiJcHxwhl3AUuNwGUmUum09pKCCbdwCqHsHAs5EtLsttlKxVTOWI-iHJcliH3JSj0P42jZI8ABnWxtn0WBIEgbRxJAAAzABDAAbMLoHYCLYG2C5YvOK4sRS9LMuy7YARiuKmCRYJioyrLIquL1KuDDUirS%20qyquTMWpAbNao60rGvoDdeq3AaSoanKrgw3r8Imzrhts8p8uWnTpDqzKSlW6L1Nk9RSE0UiqSuZZNF2BgjBkUwk2xQ7wHlAEzuqnT5FQYxUBu8w7qO%20UvWer0IiukwJh%20h74z7Z7%20rej6vosA7fr-NNnvGmHrtB1T7uO8i%20BWea0ZB27McRtbuiOqzXuBz6MfYABjEA6iuOoPigNgIEgT6sBIKy8EkSILFQCQwHmZmRDqPkzMZvh5V2TYHCex6AoZqF2XlhwMnp%20XUnlh1WfgdnZD8VwlXg%20DKCUQXKGFmxeQ1bHAZF91NALfoPE1iINV5CMYH1qBVGWRZMEHSBueYfADEt63lb6yH5ULeIrwPHcWcsd2Y7-HdXl8Nm-eYMPmT5ew6EgOgI6FuXvxEbHDwTg9EgccgVLp6ONwboC9ZIP2EF0XACGQJp0AIWdKDpFRy5tgjpaoijo7E2eO2b4iRi8xcfc7jni73Ko85jEP%20DLq2K9J7HHMdkymb0Uj3MXvQKej0PgjXg3KljX0h6ssB%20-SSPNiiC-aEKr-F60doQ2A9knHUNRax9gLH2KBDM0wNxwlBSum5daITATjWehFMEWR8tZJCkU9yjCiqFXAsgc6rm9FFD02x1hyW7rjPIjC0ijhysQg4RDzgpwpLla8uUeE4hYRcXKhU%20oUN9lQvYLCLQyN1tIq4sjFHyMIewn4AFyo1XIbgShsxqHEJDFw9s61eFNT9NsVs041E6mmq1LE2jdEmmkcQ8cRi3wKPoK42xIB3GqJYT1bY-UHGSL0c4kaGjiE8WoUzDRTN24eSGCw0a2xxrBM7lI3hxCpKHBYXPBhM0RLbDyZGIxs0imwXETokJTjMl8DcP4FhD98l1MUlFUyVjGl328Y5SpjicKuFMM9CyO0770AAMoABkADyAAVUg7ABlkywatDC4zpkzMwAsqySyNyrQ3Gs2ZuAtmDJWJmVamYDkzLUIsgGGpVpekuegY5SyASrVZCASZsyEDPOenQqq5UPnrMgM8hy8oSAk0uVHUFGc2iWAAB6RQIEgRAzDEAoB%20CaMAtMAC2AAdMKYUAAuABXAARri3FAA7AAFLTAA9pSyl0BaaErpRBAAlOwBFMVIboEYDFUiPB-gmgACYAEswr0sZcywlXLVjyFCLYTA8hfRMBNMgHF%20LCUQWSrTaAFLKUMvxbTZKEERVytgMgPsJc8RIqgFatVaZICaqJTqvVBqjVhVJbqgA1gAB1SslJl7AoKlGisgJYoUqCWG4LAXAVV8RxqCPiLEcIZDrQjmoUN%20ILKWqWHfW%20lhFlxoTQ4S1KwuQgAAGozJmc8vN8VbCtn0PQGtdbi0RrqeUZtozq21otSOSINA80sEFXwEQbb8W4oAI74ogsygAbvi1KdKrBaoABbzrCuuulqVzXbSqrm9SBb5hwQjNGgULQVkjEtIJeIB5daxmvgekac4wLIMstZEyWdxCnu-ViEgPD70%20JZsqkxKD07BEwCzRCwGlQCnjU3CDgM%20qu1g8EFNTApKQQwzVTD6GogSyiDGHDf9rShFeleqqPVoxwJhPc6SIwHYvuAZaUBthVoXG1LLCesLYUwkad5PQ%200SjCKHPiHjRiKpcldEY5qVY2oCeIT1Xs6QlOvvzKglouSb0CRwUY3NOaT10oeuDDD1B3AWwgDuQQj9FyKqhNaCNWYlAgE4Iu-FAB1ZKC7oCJTZdisK7ATOLCrvKKEFnLpj0kGJdUkB5BiFC7QEAMyAAawWeDyHCwSIeUXLYSFi-GhLixMvJe1HoEYyLmDtGq1VnSixzo8Gs01sraaKtRHAAgGgeguvJc4OlkLu4zO%20CsggUwFt3CaCOkN75QA)

The simulation above is for one signal line in the bus, being driven from slot 1 and being received by 7 other devices. The disconnect switches aren't real components, they're just there so I can simulate what happens with fewer cards installed. The backplane is represented by everything left of the switches, and the cards are represented by everything to the right of the switches.

Pulling the bus toward VTT centres the received waveform around a fairly typical threshold voltage, ensuring that low and high regions of the waveform are seen as 0 and 1 at the receive side. Unfortunately, it doesn't address the much larger problem of drive current. I'm seeing 400mApk and 260mArms per signal, which doesn't seem viable - that's more than 10A RMS (33W) burned on termination alone across the bus. There's also a lot of timing skew between slots.

I then tried serial termination instead:

[image: 8-slot bus driven from slot 1, with VTT attached to slots 1 and 8 via 100 ohm resistors, and 50 ohm series termination. The driver has a 20 ohm resistor in series to moderate the drive current.]

[(simulate in Falstad)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCBMCmC0YGYQE4B0AGdYDsjGYFZIwAOCBAFhAJAqQLjDACgAlEANnRPGw84rpe-CJGqYJmcKg40wMmkPSoCzUmK48c-AhSraQQiPOOpsIBKiTpmAdxCxkIvg6dRuhtblf9IHx77YYkZWDPBCBEIIwcwA5g4cVH48sBQ8yYae8bCJUEEOaXnBnvYBRT4W6FQ2pW4IVRUICPw1Fs3CFiT6LjbxTSLIYv3uPEpeooIdwwZRVgiMEUYtcVCTYIOrQhlj9hRg-PVUFLmHWW0HfudXYzgTUQ3Dp7NNC%20Lgy-GQk9Fb3%201jACcrqc9gcGotmEDhnQxKDaNFMpFxpt4UN2jDMpYXuE3vsSrQ8RjjkcEa0yoIhOTSSsckcpKkeBTMjZbo12uSpCEEGEwIsLDFsid2YVhmNBUdcgzaLkbt5yZK3ERRtJua9IvyzrTqJAUoUlcy7BV9WUCFx8XDTUJidQzSzvF8ImbhpbMXM1UtPFD2i6LbbxCsHbRCoHrWKrnoeNCZfj5VQqTFajoNibbStnS5nRsw4GCC4c1nPVcOCRGXji8qkazA%20WiyXXdjebjlrsy3XrTWyW5ZPwyh3DWUgpSu3XeldsA92oODZ9JuOkrPLrK7iAyAd2qv6-Mceq8a04RvrRvO-xsF0KkeablT3HCteDayB5cB2euTy%20dTxSAp1Kpztz4UygvPp1wRYYumVUdAxIBEoMKQErmQPQCX4RDqn9KtJlQhCkOeLdGx3ZtkJQJDrSw48UDAMQyjIy8qGQSiCh4ejijtCBAIAtxmMyeRVW3KIBQSKhwMYlc4JjTiXGonC03aJwolknozkDOSUWQRSbC9ER0HyOFeXyCEZyMbh0jWXk0NYlE9LRLT9IsN0%20PeM5pmMq4mHBc08Ss6V9G0hMKjMocbIErUApE0KlwqNSezccKVTfN4P0ElBJMKKKDQAZxXIwXH2bKWkyAAzABDAAbdLoGYTKSHufQnXcoRirKiqqqtBFctRZkQEa8rKqym0lkdJRCtKnqWs4Ot2o7Yamt66qV08s0j2m0a%20qw9qyOW5q%20q89qvKG7qKvsXa8zWHo1BIMQCAY05czBNC5FQUxzCxTx1GoBiMVujqImkJ67Osc7LoYl0vpdH6TGkZ6rFei73o0Osvqmh6-pellYausQNy%20pbkch-6YaBsQsK%20jbcfkKGAbejHwF86gctp8HHrx1HmAAY28yoJSoUUoEYCBlGq%20oiAoJxIFzPh9IwLAVmtKNuaIA1dhOBpqaeQ1rU%20j7Eo13INbmsZ2Y1hEdbQmB4H5mRi3ovgwAIcXdBIZBDCllglaoEHgdTeJrQIDZ2w8A2OZ9XJfeKM2mGdu2OGwYXjjFohsBwl31dyGtqb7b2r0ua1sH%20TxDdTtss6G8OLeOXAECcEhcDobA1OsZO3fmnQGKAjnhMPaMbALoTCVyYStj553K%20rrpbegvQ7cERRG454mGJozO6JcUiC27ueSNyNLB-N4eRYQC6iAIC7BnQAgEHMZRMFdjmvOpvaZdyNyufASihvX60vM-szMlL4ecGwIA9YMda623%20LPdqpxAxqyOmaDEIZqSwMGiiMGhpJp1mrCONBi08RQV3JCK4B48Q41aOtJCylpJIJpvkQMD9WR5W2opDgMgh4ETOHNdYmMtgBzOEYAs2x8QMLKDMQ0NVGjghWPxIaPNRxzR%20H1GRyIxFyPcswjgrCPStFalRNwGJRxWjEqGdhBieBzSMRZbRfU9GcBYbvNhWj%20pGi9oiRSodpx9WxhENeSjHFzTBjY9RdjNGiPGikYcoxJFfncr%20YxUShJCBiRY0JfUppqI0Y5BxG5AL4PiEIaCxQB6xPyX1QpSSNxzSWmkoJGSQlYSktUSJKkhDb1iSpOaLSklYXaThAJ6T8H2CMvkYRDNIm8hHK-eqKwOEuQ4T-CKgyuHUOKFUiO9jmB%20HMF9Lymglm0BAAAZQADIAHkAAqJB1naTpihJCOysJUCOWc7AlzNkuA3Dsg8ByTmnI4C865ySdk1ged81QGz-kuh2T6L5ZyKB-K%20hiHZRJoWnIQHCjMDQdkgmRZAP5n8dS0Bivi4FZyb54sZE-M6AAPVw4AETeFtkcRyYBWYAFsAA66V0oABcACuAAjNlbKAB2AAKVmAB7IVQroCsy5eKgEABKZg1KYoUDkPkMAhRaogAACYAEt0oSqlTKrlyqoCV1pTQeoTtbbmG1QQVlHKuUAiKqzaAgqhWSo5azIqAIdVmtgH4JI7JeROzFoyRykBHXcpdW6j1Xr0p8tdQAawAA4lSKtKghwjJLHXyryGw7BUhSGpqkPUDEhprFQCxSO2aYq03gGaPaNMbBguLREBisBmg8GplQAAaqc05fzG1CIyAYftg7h27QbWO2mE6h3UtSIqPYDgEDrGoCRRyA7TkcrZQARw5QCGVAA3DlJVxW2CdQACyPelK94qSr%20ofIqZMXZTTcVCO6DUo4tRuKlG4sMWpuwiWA3%20XQ3R%20CfzOkCKDBwzwzHcMwcV4AxCUWVIIZAWhq0z35l%20cATstjKgtVaRQ1BSPR0yKwE9HKADqRVj3QAKvKll6UkPgHfWhzIGGe3O0kFFU0YtwBQHYwcEApyAAabHbZyHxVadAmHeMSD4JAZAlc1VrsE1fCQ-GOCCeMPoO2Fh2NoQZUZsB3Fz5mYVkYBWSBba4fs1ZoatsojgBFtxdzSBWCSeQz2it7HSDyeoM7UQwnIzMCAA)

This seems to work pretty well. The timing skew between slots is reduced significantly compared to the parallel termination design, and the drive current is significantly lower.

The value of the 20Ω resistor in series with the driver was determined experimentally, balancing the ΔV swing between low and high and the drive current. With 20Ω drive current is reduced to 80mApk / 55mArms per line, and the swing seems to have enough margin to produce reliable results. 18Ω may end up being a better value to give some extra headroom in practice; this is probably something we'll have to try tweaking in reference implementations.

What I'd like to know is whether this analysis looks sound, and whether there are any better options for termination in a bus like this? I considered parallel Thevenin termination on each card, rather than VTT on the backplane, but that produces a nasty stub in the case where only one card is installed and driving the bus without any receiving cards to provide termination. I've seen diode termination used in other systems too, but it isn't clear to me that those approaches are applicable here.

Comment: Have you referenced PCI bus?

Comment: Can you reduce the 5 cm trace on each card, the trace from the connector to the receiver?  As you probably know, shorter is better here.

Comment: And is this a one way (unidirectional) bus/signal, or is it bi-directional?

Comment: You also might want to look up what was done a number of years ago with Futurebus (IEEE 896) and BTL (Backplane Transceiver Logic, see TI app note snla029).

Comment: @TimWilliams Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @SteveSh If necessary we could mandate a shorter trace length in the spec, although I'd prefer not to unless there's a tangible reason that it should not be 50mm. The bus is bidirectional, yes. I'll take a look at that appnote.

Answer (score 0):

What you propose is very similar to PCI bus, at least what I recall of it. Just of fewer bits, and maybe not as clock-synchronous.

PCI has a bus on the main board, which also propagates up the card(s) for some maximum stub length, and the maximum length of the bus (width of the motherboard; length of the backplane in your case) is constrained by the clock speed. PCI physical interface seems a promising reference.

Here is the standard: [PCI Local Bus Specification Rev. 2.2](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eharris/ics216/pci/PCI_22.pdf)